# How to reproduce the result of pivot_longer with reshape in base R?

Tags: r, reshape

Consider the `cprefm` object:

```
library(conjoint)

data(chocolate)
```

With `pivot_longer`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cprefm %>% 
  pivot_longer(., 1:16, "profile", "rating") %>% 
  head(16)

# A tibble: 16 × 2
   profile   value
   <chr>     <int>
 1 profile1     14
 2 profile2     15
 3 profile3      5
 4 profile4      2
 5 profile5      1
 6 profile6     11
 7 profile7      3
 8 profile8     10
 9 profile9     16
10 profile10    13
11 profile11    12
12 profile12     7
13 profile13     6
14 profile14     9
15 profile15     4
16 profile16     8
```

I couldn't reproduce this with the reshape function:

```
cprefm |>
  (\(x) reshape(x, varying = 1:16, times = names(x)[1:16], timevar = "profile", 
                v.names = "values", direction = "long"))() |> 
  (\(x) head(x, 16))()

             profile values id
1.profile1  profile1     14  1
2.profile1  profile1     16  2
3.profile1  profile1      7  3
4.profile1  profile1      9  4
5.profile1  profile1      7  5
6.profile1  profile1     14  6
7.profile1  profile1      3  7
8.profile1  profile1      2  8
9.profile1  profile1      1  9
10.profile1 profile1      4 10
11.profile1 profile1      4 11
12.profile1 profile1     14 12
13.profile1 profile1      7 13
14.profile1 profile1     14 14
15.profile1 profile1     10 15
16.profile1 profile1      4 16
```

I have tried in many ways to modify `varying` argument, but I have not been able to reproduce the behavior of `tidyr::pivot_longer`. Note that even `row.names` has column names, but I wouldn't like that either.

I would like it to look identical to `pivot_longer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) post process** The reshape command in the question produces the same output except for row names, row order and an extra id column so just fix those up.

At the end we run pivot_longer and converting its output to data.frame show that that is identical to the fixed-up output of reshape.

```
out <- reshape(cprefm, dir = "long", varying = names(cprefm), 
  v.names = "value", timevar = "profile", times = names(cprefm))
out <- out[order(out$id), 1:2]
rownames(out) <- NULL

out.piv <- cprefm %>% pivot_longer(1:16, "profile", "rating")

identical(out, as.data.frame(out.piv))
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) pre process w transpose** Alternately fix it up *before* passing it to reshape by reshaping the transpose of cprefm.  In that case we only have to  select out the desired columns while the row order comes out as desired without sorting.

```
out2 <- reshape(as.data.frame(t(cprefm)), dir = "long",
  varying = 1:nrow(cprefm), idvar = "profile", v.names = "value", 
  ids = names(cprefm), new.row.names = 1:prod(dim(cprefm)))[3:2]

identical(out2, as.data.frame(out.piv))
## [1] TRUE
```

**3) as.data.frame.table w transpose** The transpose idea also works with as.data.frame.table:

```
out3 <- with(as.data.frame.table(t(cprefm), responseName = "value"),
  data.frame(profile = as.character(Var1), value))

identical(out3, as.data.frame(out.piv))
## [1] TRUE
```

This one can be nicely written in terms of pipes like this:

```
cprefm |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame.table(responseName = "value") |>
  with(data.frame(profile = as.character(Var1), value))
```

**4) stack w tranpose** and with stack:

```
out4 <- with(stack(as.data.frame(t(cprefm))), 
  data.frame(profile = names(cprefm), value = values))

identical(out4, as.data.frame(out.piv))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Well that was comprehensive!

Answer (score 2):

If not using `reshape` is okay, this might works...

```
x <- as.data.frame(t(cprefm))

y <- data.frame(
  profile = rownames(x),
  value = unlist(x)
)
head(y,16)

     profile value
1   profile1    14
2   profile2    15
3   profile3     5
4   profile4     2
5   profile5     1
6   profile6    11
7   profile7     3
8   profile8    10
9   profile9    16
10 profile10    13
11 profile11    12
12 profile12     7
13 profile13     6
14 profile14     9
15 profile15     4
16 profile16     8
```

Answer (score 1):

For a complete pivot in `base` I'd use `stack`, no edited to fiddle it into an exact match with `pivot_longer`:

```
result = cprefm |> stack() |> setNames(c("value", "profile")) |> rev() 
result = result[order((1:nrow(result) - 1) %% nrow(cprefm), result$profile), ]
rownames(result) = 1:nrow(result)
result
#      profile value
# 1   profile1    14
# 2   profile2    15
# 3   profile3     5
# 4   profile4     2
# 5   profile5     1
# 6   profile6    11
# 7   profile7     3
# 8   profile8    10
# 9   profile9    16
# 10 profile10    13
# 11 profile11    12
# 12 profile12     7
# 13 profile13     6
# 14 profile14     9
# 15 profile15     4
# 16 profile16     8
# 17  profile1    16
# 18  profile2    15
# 19  profile3     7
# 20  profile4    14
# ...
```

Comment: But the result is ordered (`profile1`, `profile1`, `profile1` ...)

Comment: It's very easy to sort data.

Comment: In `pivot_longer` the result is `profile1`, `profile2`, `profile3`... (`14`, `15`, `5`...). `reshape` and `stack` order the values.

Comment: Okay, so just to be clear you want a result that is ordered in a specific way, but without any sort of id column or other evidence of the order, so that if it becomes disordered there is no way to notice or correct?

Comment: If the `profile` column looks the same as `pivot_longer`, that's fine.